# Germanic use of hyphens

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

Is there any way to get rid of the hyphens in the tags? If it is impossible to have spaces, could we not at least have the traditional underscores? This use of hyphens is a violation of modern English usage, although I see it all the time in papers written by foreigners, especially from the Continent, where it has to be corrected before publication....

Comment: I don't really understand why this question got so many downvotes. You don't have to agree with the viewpoint of @joseph, but I think the question in itself is a fair one. Upvoted answers is more what matters, in my opinion.

Answer (score 6):

Tags are not meant to be interpreted as single English words, so it's not a violation of modern English usage. Rather, a tag is an example of a "slug," a condensed representation of a title or phrase used in a situation where a limited character set is allowed. The hyphen is the traditional word separator for slugs on websites.

Incidentally, the set of allowed characters in a tag is lowercase letters, digits, `+`, `-`, `#`, and `.`. Underscores are not permitted.